# Converting native javascript code to aura component javascript

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, javascript-controller

I have the following JS code  and I'm trying to convert to aura component JS Controller, I'm getting error on the `yield` how would you make equivalent aura component code

```
    function* createChunkGenerator(
         itemList = [], chunkSize = 1, chunkCount = 0
    ) {
        chunkSize = Math.max(chunkSize, 1);

     while (itemList.length >= 1) {
       ++chunkCount;
       yield {
        chunkCount,
        itemList: itemList.splice(0, chunkSize),
      };
    }
}

const chunkGenerator = createChunkGenerator(data, 5);
```

Aura component javascript:

```
 createChunkGenerator: function( ) { 

    //....
 },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aura doesn't support ES6 function generators, it only [supports ES5 and ES6 Promises](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_supported_es.htm). Either import the function as a third-party library with [ltng:require](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.206.0.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ltng_require.htm), or use a Lightning Web Component (LWC), which supports everything your browser supports (with limitations based on [Locker Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer) or [Lightning Web Security](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/lws-distortion-viewer), whichever you're using). You can also write an LWC, and then call that LWC from Aura:

## utils.js

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
export default class Utils extends LightningElement {
  @api *createChunkGenerator(
    itemList = [], chunkSize = 1, chunkCount = 0
  ) {
    chunkSize = Math.max(chunkSize, 1);
    while (itemList.length >= 1) {
      ++chunkCount;
      yield {
        chunkCount,
        itemList: itemList.splice(0, chunkSize),
      };
    }
  }
}
```

## utils.html

```
<template></template>
```

## Aura CMP

```
<aura:component>
  <c:utils aura:id="utils" />
</aura:component>
```

## Aura Controller

```
myFunction: function(component, event, helper) {
  let generator = component.find("utils").createChunkGenerator(data, 5);
  // Rest of logic here
}
```

Comment: wow, how do you know all this lol

Comment: @ThreeOneThree Just a few decades of computer science experience, and a passion for learning new things .